# Squeezing to find a limit

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let:   $$\ I_{n}=\int _{0}^{\pi/4 }\tan ^{n}\left( x\right) dx$$
 Knowing that $$I_{n+2}+I_{n}=\dfrac {1} {n+1}$$ 
   which can be proved easily.
And $$I_{n+1}\leq I_{n}$$

Prove that:  $$\dfrac {1} {2\left( n+1\right) }\leq In\leq \dfrac {1} {n+1}$$

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I have already given a proof of such inequality in my answer to your previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254714/integral-inequalities-and-recurrence/2254759?noredirect=1#comment4637032_2254759)

Comment: That's what I did,I've given all I reached.

Comment: $$I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^n}{1+u^2}\,du $$ is obviously bounded between $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^n}{2}\,du$ and $\int_{0}^{1}u^n\,du$.

Comment: Didn't see it ,sry !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral inequalities and recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254714/integral-inequalities-and-recurrence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your induction relation :
$$2I_{n+2}\le I_{n+2}+I_n=\frac{1}{n+1} \le 2I_n$$
So, by reading this the other way around :
$$\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\le I_n \le \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$
which seems an even better bounding of $I_n$, because it gives you an equivalent : $I_n\sim \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: BTW, if you want your exact bound, you can just say : $I_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-I_{n+2}\le \frac{1}{n+1}$ because $I_{n+2}>0$.